# standard conversions:Qualification conversions

Tags: c++

This is the point from ISO :Standard Conversions:Array-to-pointer conversion: $4.4: Qualification conversions /5th point

```
    A multi-level pointer to member type, or a multi-level mixed pointer and
     pointer to member type has the form:
           cv 0 P 0 to cv 1 P 1 to . . . cv n − 1 P n − 1 to cv n T
    where P i is either a pointer or pointer to member and where T is not a
    pointer type or pointer to member type.
```

Can any one Explain this.If possible give the example ..
What actually meant for that form.Can any one eloborate it ?
Similarly ..There are different form in that section(Qualification conversions)

Answer (score 3):

A *multilevel pointer* is a pointer to a pointer.

Variables can be `const` or `volatile` normally (these are called *cv-qualifiers*).  When you have a pointer, both the pointed-to data and the pointer itself can have cv-qualifiers.  When you have a multilevel pointer, there can be cv-qualifiers at any level.

For example:

```
int i1 = 1;
const int i2 = 2;
int * p1 = &i1; // p1 is a non-constant pointer to a non-constant int
int * const p2 = &i1; // p2 is a constant pointer to a non-constant int
int const * p3 = &i2; // p3 is a non-constant pointer to a constant int
const int * p4 = &i2; // same as p3
int const * const p5 = &i2; // p5 is a constant pointer to a constant int
int * * pp1 = &p1; // non-const pointer to non-const pointer to non-const int
int * * const pp2 = &p1; // const pointer to non-const pointer to non-const int
int * const * pp3 = &p2; // non-const pointer to const pointer to non-const int
int const * * pp4 = &p3; // non-const pointer to non-const pointer to const int
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

They're simply saying that you can have a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to ...to something other than a pointer. At each of those steps along the way, you can have `const`, `volatile`, or both. So, for example, you could have:

```
int const * volatile *const volatile x;
```

which means `x` is a const, volatile pointer to a volatile pointer to a const int.

Comment: the example u gave is nothing but Multi-level poiner type..can u able to tell me,  full statement represents for

Comment: @BE Student: I was trying to clarify the piece you posted, which only covers a multi-level pointer, in which each level potentially has separate qualifiers. That's all it really says. I'm not sure what you mean by: "can u able to tell me, full statement represents for"

Comment: a multi-level mixed pointer and  pointer to member type has the form: