# standard conversions:Qualification conversions

Tags: c++

This is the point from ISO :Standard Conversions:Array-to-pointer conversion: $4.4: Qualification conversions /6th point

- **Continuation for the Question:**

[standard conversions:Qualification conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274014/standard-conversionsqualification-conversions)

```
     Two multi-level pointer to member types or two multi-level mixed pointer 
     and pointer to member types T1 and T2 are similar if there exists a type T
     and integer n > 0 such that:

  T 1 is cv 1 , 0 P 0 to cv 1 , 1 P 1 to . . . cv 1 , n − 1 P n − 1 to cv 1 , n T
                             and
  T 2 is cv 2 , 0 P 0 to cv 2 , 1 P 1 to . . . cv 2 , n − 1 P n − 1 to cv 2 , n T
```

What it meant for?
Please check the previous question also?
Can any one Explain this.If possible give the example .. What actually meant for that form.Can any one eloborate if  it  is possible.

other question:

Why the standard is going for such form.Is there any reason fo this?

Comment: Do you understand why you can't convert `T**` to `T const**` without casting?

Answer (score 0):

This rule is part of the rules that tell you whether there is a conversion from `int*const*` to `int volatile**`. You can see that they're *similar*, because they're both **two** levels of indirection away from **`int`**.

When converting between two *similar* types, you have to use the conversion rules for *similar* types. There are different rules when converting between two types that are not *similar*.